# Can I disobey a police order if I have reason to believe that to obey would put my life in imminent danger?

Tags: criminal-law, california

Suppose I am detained by a police officer and ordered to remain in the exact spot. However, the officer doesn't notice that I am three seconds away from potentially being impaled by someone or something. Or, the officer knows and still refuses to allow me to move. Am I legally free to ignore the order to stay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

California law has a general defense of necessity.  It appears that it's not in statute, but rather comes from common law.  It's described in what appears to be the official jury instructions at [CALCRIM 3403](https://www.justia.com/criminal/docs/calcrim/3400/3403/).

> The defendant is not guilty of (insert crime[s]) if (he/she)
>   acted because of legal necessity.
>
> In order to establish this defense, the defendant must prove that:
>
> 1. (He/She) acted in an emergency to prevent a signiﬁcant bodily
>      harm or evil to (himself/herself/ [or] someone else);
> 2. (He/She) had no adequate legal alternative;
> 3. The defendant’s acts did not create a greater danger than the
>      one avoided;
> 4. When the defendant acted, (he/she) actually believed that the act
>      was necessary to prevent the threatened harm or evil;
> 5. A reasonable person would also have believed that the act was
>      necessary under the circumstances;
>
> AND
>
> 6. The defendant did not substantially contribute to the emergency.
>
> The defendant has the burden of proving this defense by a
>   preponderance of the evidence. This is a different standard of proof
>   than proof beyond a reasonable doubt. To meet the burden of proof by
>   a preponderance of the evidence, the defendant must prove that it is
>   more likely than not that each of the six listed items is true.

It seems like all six requirements would apply in your hypothetical case, so if you could prove them, you'd be off the hook for a violation of Cal. Penal 148(a)(1) as cited by user6726.

Answer (score -1):

[Cal. Penal 148(a)(1)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=2800) says

> Every person who willfully resists, delays, or obstructs any public
>   officer, peace officer, or an emergency medical technician, as defined
>   in Division 2.5 (commencing with Section 1797) of the Health and
>   Safety Code, in the discharge or attempt to discharge any duty of his
>   or her office or employment, when no other punishment is prescribed,
>   shall be punished by a fine not exceeding one thousand dollars
>   ($1,000), or by imprisonment in a county jail not to exceed one year,
>   or by both that fine and imprisonment.

There is no exception clause / affirmative defense whereby a reasonable belief of imminent danger negates the charge. There are defenses if the officer's is acting unlawfully, or you are defending yourself against excessive force: i.e. if the officer is breaking the law.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see how that law would play out in the courtroom if I ever were to be charged like that. I suppose it could be argued, after all, that enforcement of the order in such a case would constitute unlawful deprivation of a Constitutional right

Comment: I think there actually is a necessity defense that would apply.  See my answer.